# Example 12 All Permutations of a string from Big O notation why line 7 and line 10+11 take O(n) time - Cracking the Coding Interview

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I don't understand why the reason for executing line 7 and line 10+11 takes O(n) time.

For line 7, is it the direct execution of making the string where 1) the action of printing a string (e.g. the computer internally has to print a then b then c on the screen) is O(n) or is it because 2) for all the permutations we have a different System.out.println(prefix) printed? but if its 1) does that mean every print statement is O(n) in every function? and if its 2) why isn't this part of the n! in O(n*n!) since this is done at the same time with line 5-14 for every possible permutation of the string.

Similarly, for line 10+11 is the reason because when java concatenates it does so by creating a string that takes every letter 1 by 1 from the different sub strings to create the newly concatenated string?

```
void permutation(String str){
   permutation(str,"");
}

void permutation(String str, String prefix){               // line 5
  if(str.length()==0){
    System.out.println(prefix);                            // line 7
  } else{
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
      String rem=str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1);    // line 10
      permutation(rem,prefix+str.charAt(i));               // line 11
    }
  }
}                                                          // line 14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define what `n` even is. A sensible definition in this cas is that `n` is the size of the original input `str` (as that's the primary dimension that will vary and influence performance).

Printing `prefix` in line 7 can easily be argued to be O(n) because for `str.length == 0` to be true, the prefix has to be the same size of `str` (i.e. it has length `n`) and printing `n` characters takes (asymptotically) `n` time units (printing more takes more time).

Does that mean every `System.out.println` is O(n)? Well, no. Because not every `System.out.println` will have a variable-sized input. `System.out.println("Hello")` is O(1), because no matter what happens around it, it'll always take the same time (at least at the granularity that matters for big-O).

Line `10` is O(n) because it will copy `n-1` characters (which will be reduced to O(n), because big-O doesn't care about constant factors like `-1`).

My big-O times are too long ago to really do the calculation for line 11 now, Sorry. I'll leave that for someone else to answer.

And important caveat in this to keep in mind is that big-O is a **big** generalization and (intentionally) glosses over a lot of details.

One action that is O(1) can be *much slower* or *much faster* than another that also takes O(1), because the *constant factors are ignored*.

So just because "`System.out.println` printing n characters is O(n)" doesn't mean that it's slow: it can be incredibly fast and in many cases the difference between printing 1, 3, 5 or even 1000 characters could be almost unmeasurably small. But to big-O notation the only thing that matters is that for *big values of `n`* it will grow roughly linearly.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously line 11 **have not** `O(n)` cost.

In fact, the cost is `T(n) = (n-1)!` (for each other char run again).

You can write traces to be obvious:

```
static int permutation(String str){
    return permutation(str,"");
}

static int permutation(String str, String prefix){
    if(str.length()==0){
        System.out.println(prefix);
        return 1;
    } else{
        int cost = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            String rem=str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1);
            int c = permutation(rem,prefix+str.charAt(i));
            System.out.printf("LINE 11 cost: %d (current size %d)%n", c, str.length());
            cost += c;
        }
        return cost;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%nTOTAL COST: %d%n", permutation("ABCDE"));
}
```

with output

```
...
LINE 11 cost: 1 (current size 1)
LINE 11 cost: 1 (current size 2)
EDCBA
LINE 11 cost: 1 (current size 1)
LINE 11 cost: 1 (current size 2)
LINE 11 cost: 2 (current size 3)
LINE 11 cost: 6 (current size 4)
LINE 11 cost: 24 (current size 5)

TOTAL COST: 120
```

(`permutation(str)` take `O(factorial(str.length()))` time)

NOTE: if you take string concatenation into account you don't have to take `O(n * n!)` since Java has a `Strings` cache. On the other hand, if you consider the time to print strings, then yes it is `O(n * n!)` since each character must be printed with a total of `n * n!` characters (plus EOL and so).